# ArangoDB connection in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, arangodb

How would I go about using ArangoDB in Lumen?
I have added arango to my composer. ("triagens/arangodb": "v3.8.0")
The setup connection options here:
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/drivers/php-tutorial.html

Where would I add this code in Lumen? in the bootstrap app.php?

After successfully adding it, how would I use the connection in my controllers?

I have used it before with Slim Framework, then I had access to the connection via the DI and had it setup vi dependencies file, but with Lumen Im not sure.

grateful for any help!

Comment: Have you tried [laravel-arangodb](https://github.com/LaravelFreelancerNL/laravel-arangodb) package?

Comment: thank you for the link. no i have not, but i would still want to learn the answer to my question. any idea?

Comment: Follow the documentation [Connect to ArangoDB](https://github.com/LaravelFreelancerNL/laravel-arangodb/blob/next/docs/connect-to-arangodb.md) and I guess it's easy to setup, you just need to put few entries in `config/database.php` and `.env` file